# dygraph.resize doesn't works with a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, dygraphs

I use a directive to draw a dygraph .

```
<i>
    <div ng-switch-when="1" id="graph-div">
        <div id = "labels" align = "center"  onchange="resizeElements()"></div>
        <graphdrawarea data="plotData" events="plotEvents" options="plotOptions" index="serieOfRangeSelectorIndex"></graphdrawarea>
    </div>
<i>
```

directive:

```
scope.options.width=elm[0].parentElement.clientWidth;
$scope.graph = new Dygraph(elm.children()[0].childNodes[0],scope.data , scope.options );
$scope.graph.ready(function() {
    $scope.graph.setAnnotations(scope.events);
});
```

but when i used to resize the windows, the graph doesn't do it automatically.
PS: I also declare the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tied graph.resize(width, height); after graph.ready like this

```
graph.ready(function(){
    graph.resize(1016,320);
});
```